# Developing an API in C

Tags: c, api, biometrics

I received a task to develop an API in C for a biometric reader and I have no idea where can I start.
The API is going to be used in the ATM's applications we develop here.
I've never done something like this so, could you please help me? An example should help a lot!

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an API from the vendor? Or are you working for the vendor?

Comment: This is kindof a HUGE task. Maybe there is already an API in another language, so you could look there. And you need the technical docs of the device. And I'd recommend you to remove the name of the vendor from the question so that you don't get in trouble with your "unofficial" project. (I won't turn you in; I did not even flag the question although it is really too broad)

Answer (score 2):

Being the first time, consider going back to the basics and pick a development methodology.  The most basic would require you (first and foremost) define requirements for the API, design the interface, implement the interface, unit-test the interface and then release it to your customer for system level integration.  Start here... [Software development process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process)